# What would cause my Windows machine to seize?

Tags: windows-xp

I run Windows XP SP2 on a Desktop I built (I know that doesn't provide much, but I can't say "on a Dell X103938R" or something).

It has 'seized' about 7 times in its year and a half life. Everything freezes. I can't move the mouse cursor and the keyboard seems unresponsive. I can turn the monitor on and off and it will hold the last image. The light for the mouse is responsive if I move it. The keyboard lights change when pressed (cap locks, etc).

I've waited upto ten minutes for a change, nothing.

I haven't connected any activity to the seizing. It's happened when all I was "running" were fullscreen programs (games), just checking email, or once when I was sitting at my desktop (I was reading a book and when I tried to use the mouse, nothing).

I've never been able to figure it out. I have to hard reset, and then its fine. It doesn't file system check or anything (not sure if Windows does that). No error when I load up the computer, nothing.

If I had uTorrent open, it will have to recheck the torrent files to make sure they weren't corrupted though. (It's not always open when it seizes either).

I'm using an AMD Athlon 5400+ with a NVidia GeForce 8600 GT, if that helps. I'm using two hard drives, 500Gb Wester Digital with a 1Tb Hitachi.

Comment: What motherboard does it have? The M/B defines most of the compatibility of the system.

Answer (score 3):

There are a ton of things that it could be. Overheating, bad memory, outdated/bad drivers (video especially) and power fluctuations come to mind. You can start with [memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/) to start with.

Also 7 times in a year and a half isn't too bad. I'm guessing that since Windows isn't fully patched and up to date, neither are your drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Until you can get us more information....

Are there any question marks in Device Manager? Eliminating those can help stability.

A poor quality power supply can be an issue, especially if there are other power issues on the line.

Are you running the latest BIOS?

Have you tried clearing CMOS, accepting defaults, and running with those for a while?

Are lockups associated with USB usage? If so, this could be either a grounding or a driver issue.

The first place to start is emgee's suggestion, run memtest86+, and run it a long time, like overnight or better yet over a 3 day weekend.